# Boost::python and Eigen/dense create a segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, boost, eigen3

I want to use an Eigen/dense object in a structure like this:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct data_t {
    Eigen::Matrix2f matrix;
    //std::vector<float> matrix;
};

data_t init_data() {
    data_t result;
    result.matrix(0, 0) = 1.0f;
    result.matrix(0, 1) = 2.0f;
    result.matrix(1, 0) = 3.0f;
    result.matrix(1, 1) = 4.0f;
    //result.matrix.push_back(1.0f);
    //result.matrix.push_back(2.0f);
    //result.matrix.push_back(3.0f);
    //result.matrix.push_back(4.0f);
    return result;
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_test) {

    boost::python::class_<data_t>("DataType")
        .def("from_init", &init_data)
        .staticmethod("from_init")
    ;
}
```

The python code looks like:

```
import python_test

def init_data():
    return python_test.DataType.from_init()

sample = init_data()
```

The execution causes a segmentation fault. My question is: why? If I replace the Eigen object with a std::vector the code runs fine.

Comment: The follwong works:

    struct data_t {  Eigen::MatrixXf matrix;};

and: 

    data_t init_data() {
        data_t result;
        result.matrix = Eigen::Matrix2f();
        result.matrix(0, 0) = 1.0f;
        result.matrix(0, 1) = 2.0f;
        result.matrix(1, 0) = 3.0f;
        result.matrix(1, 1) = 4.0f;
        return result;
    }

Comment: I guess the problem is that a fixed size Eigen object is internally passed by value to a boost::python function during the return statement. (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicPassingByValue.html)

Comment: You can try to disable static alignment using `-D EIGEN_MAX_STATIC_ALIGN_BYTES=0`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: Could you provide a stack-trace of the failure? Also, does it make a difference if you compile with our without optimization?

Comment: Switching **NDEBUG** off results in the alignment assertion failure. 
Switching optimisation off results in a linker error: 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/test.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sgetrf_'
//usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Comment: gdb says the seg fault occurs here: 
execute<boost::reference_wrapper<data_t const> const> (x=...) at /usr/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:45
45             Derived::construct(&instance->storage, (PyObject*)instance, x)->install(raw_result);

Comment: So as assumed it looks like an alignment issue -- which should be worked-around by disabling static alignment. If `EIGEN_MAX_STATIC_ALIGN_BYTES` does not work, you may be using an old Eigen version. Try `-D EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY` instead (or upgrade your Eigen version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `data_t` contains a matrix which Eigen expects to be aligned, but which Boost::Python fails to allocate on aligned memory.

The easiest workaround is to disable alignment for only this (make a typedef, if you use this more often):

```
struct data_t {
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2, Eigen::DontAlign> matrix;
};
```

Alternatively, disable static alignment all-together, by compiling with `-D EIGEN_MAX_STATIC_ALIGN_BYTES=0` (on recent Eigen versions) or `-D EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY` for older Eigen versions.

Actually, if Boost::Python uses `operator::new` to allocate its objects, the following might work as well:

```
struct data_t {
    Eigen::Matrix2f matrix;
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
};
```